# Upgraded emacs and now there's extra whitespace around latex equations using org-latex-preview

Tags: org-mode, latex

This is inside a docstring in a python script, using org-preview-latex:
[image]

After rendering:

[image]

The whitespace goes away if I run `convert -trim ltximg/org-ltximg_60b58ddb1d181ad22bd828dd88e5039cf2e80a89.png ltximg/org-ltximg_60b58ddb1d181ad22bd828dd88e5039cf2e80a89.png` manually:

[image]

This problem did not happen before the system upgrade - it used to trim correctly. Any hints on how to go about debugging this?